# salt-cloud minion install/config on windows VM

Tags: salt-stack, salt-cloud

I'm trying to test salt-cloud with vmWare/vCenter and all is really good so far. However it appears the minion is not being installed on the VM. I have been digging around and the only settings I find are

http://salt-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windows.html

```
my-softlayer:
  provider: softlayer
  user: MYUSER1138
  apikey: 'e3b68aa711e6deadc62d5b76355674beef7cc3116062ddbacafe5f7e465bfdc9'
  minion:
    master: saltmaster.example.com
  **win_installer: /root/Salt-Minion-0.17.0-AMD64-Setup.exe
  win_username: Administrator
  win_password: letmein**
```

Does this mean, I need to have the windows installer in /root for salt-cloud to run? I thought setting deploy: True would do the install. Below is my config. my vlan is using dhcp, so I am getting a good IP and all.

cloud.profile.d/test.conf

```
windows-test:
  provider: vcenter
  clonefrom: 'Win2K12'
  num_cpus: 1
  memory: 2GB
  devices:
    network:
      Network adapter 1:
        name: vlan
        adapter_type: vmxnet3
        switch_type: distributed
  cluster: cluster
  datastore: datastore
  folder: 'OS Testing'
  power_on: True
  deploy: True
  customization: False
  win_username: Administrator
  win_password: password
  minion:
    master: salt
```

**EDIT**
I do have to specify the installer location. That seems to work. The problem now is trying to get pywinrm/Windows Remote Management to work. For some reason salt-cloud is trying to connect on 5986, but looking at the VM I see WRM is listening on 5985. So I'm wondering if it's a pywinrm setting now???

Comment: have some similar issue with that winrm port. did you figure out anything?

Comment: our engineering team, did not care for the winrm setup. So it was shelved, I think we will end up with a pre-installed minion and use some states to alter what we need. But one option was pre-configure win-rm on the image to open up the needed ports/certificate, install the minion, and then apply a state to shut win-rm down.